# Styling the reddit widget

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am trying to apply the following style changes to the reddit widget:

1) Change font to Oxygen Mono (the !important override in CSS is not working for font, although it is working for link color)

2) Trim the top of the widget to eliminate the blue bar completely

3) Prevent widget_arrows.gif from being displayed in the widget.

Any ideas?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z4wG4/)

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen+Mono);
 html {
    font-family:'Oxygen Mono', Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#reddit {
    width:900px;
    margin:auto;
    font:'Oxygen Mono' !important;
}
#reddit a:link, #reddit a:visited, #reddit a:hover, #reddit a:active {
    color:gray !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you can override a font, you just need to specify the correct format - if you change only the font family, use `font-family`. A simple look in the debug tools also showed this as *"Rule ignored due to invalid property value"*.

As for the rest, just pick them out with the element inspector and fix them:

```
/* Style the anchors specifically for CSS specificity */
#reddit a {
    font-family:'Oxygen Mono' !important;
}
.reddit-header, .reddit-voting-arrows {
    display:none !important;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/z4wG4/1/).

Comment: Thank you!  Very elegant and much more simple than I thought.  Which debug tools did you use to find the invalid property value?  Built in the browser or there's something in jsfiddle?

Comment: Chrome, right-click, *Inspect Element*, look at the CSS rules in the right-hand column.